# Creating a calendar in PHP

Tags: php, calendar

Are there any APIs or libraries that make it easy to generate a calendar for a certain month/year? I need to have some sort of admin interface for a "event planner" part of a CMS for a local youth group and I'm at a loss as to how to generate a decent calendar.

Note: I only need something to generate the calendar HTML, not manage events. I'll be coding that part.

Comment: APIs generally don't come with full admin interfaces. If you want an admin system, why not just use Google Calendar and export it to your site?

Comment: I mean I'm coding my own admin interface but for the "events" part I want to have a calender that displays all the events for the month and then the admin would click a link to edit it. I only need to have something generate the html for the calender

Answer (score 1):

Two Spring to Mind

1. [PHP Calendar](http://www.php-calendar.com/) - Free
2. [Easy PHP
   Calendar](http://www.easyphpcalendar.com/) - Paid ($29.99 per
   domain) but a lot slicker than PHP
   Calendar

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a jQuery plugin instead. Thanks for the suggestions

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fullcalendar